# Transfer existing website to git

Tags: php, linux, git, github, repository

I have a website which is written in php, jquery. I have just started a repository for it on github, and successfully copied a readme textfile to the site.

How do I (a) integrate the entire website into the git repository? Currently the project_git directory is at the same level as the httpdocs directory. How do I put it inside, but making sure that the website stays up and well?

(b) create a local repository which can push to this site?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Skip the README file for now and copy it.

1. Create an empty repository on github
2. `git init` in the folder where you want to track all your files, e.g. httpdocs
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m 'first commit'`
5. Add the repo on github as a remote, e.g. `git remote add origin < githubpath >`
6. Push up the master branch to github with `git push origin master`

Now you can add your README, commit and push, or do it in step 3

Comment: I already completed steps 1 through 4, and probably through 6. The problem is that I am pushing the wrong files, and I want to push the website, but am afraid to make changes to those folders. And I am not sure where I need to creare the git init and what to write in the add instead of `.` thanks~

Comment: Ok. What folder contains the complete website? Change directory to that folder on command line. This is where you should do "git init", "git add ." and "git commit -m 'blabla'". For example if the folder "httpdocs" contains everything you want to push, enter that folder and do git init etc.

Comment: thanks someone here just showed me the exact same thing. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have pushed the README.txt file to github you are all set up (with a local repository). git will not mess with your current directory structure so it should be as easy as:

`git add .`

`git commit -m "first commit of website"`

`git push origin master`

And you should see everything in github

Comment: but I think the readme file is inside a `project_git` folder, does that not matter?

Comment: should I copy the website (`httpdocs`) into `project_git` and then put it up there? or does that not matter at all?

Comment: It isn't necessary to have a project_git folder.  However, the way you structure your directories shouldn't have an effect.  usually, the readme is at the root level of the application.

Comment: perhaps you should have done the git init in the httpdocs directory (or the root directory of your app).

Comment: ok I looked at it, the project_git is in fact at the root (I think it went up there on its own eventhough I put it down in the domain)

Comment: Okay when I dod `git add var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs`it says `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`, what should I do? redo git init *inside* the httpdocs folder? somewhere else?

Comment: The important thing is where the .git directory is.  You can see it by doing a `ls -a` because it is hidden.  That should usually sit at the root.

Comment: I found it, deleted it and put it at the root. But now when I ran `git add var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs` I am getting
`fatal: pathspec 'var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs' did not match any files`

Comment: I don't think it is enough to just move it.  You might have to start again with a fresh git init.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide us with a bit more insight into your file directory structure, and probably what platform you're on would be helpful.

Also note, if you just started a free github account, pushing your site up there will make the source publicly accessible. Just something to consider.

But basically, all you need to do to put the website into github is:
1) Navigate to the root directory of the site
2) Follow the directions on github for creating a bare git repo
3) Run git add ., git commit -m "Initial commit", git push

And you should be done! Especially if you've already pushed things to the site, you've already taken care of the RSA key setup and things :)

Comment: Hi. a. I bought a paid account in github. b. I'm using plesk. the file directory is var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs - I installed git at the root, (above var), and saved the repo at the domain level of example.com (next to httpdocs, which is my website I want to eventually use with git). so I should be doing all this at the root? I am not sure I understand

Comment: Hmm, basically whatever directory you ran git init in, everything in that directory and below it is a part of the git repository. So if you ran git init somewhere that does not contain the files you are trying to back up, you will want to repeat the steps you performed to get the readme onto github, only in the highest possible directory that contains all the files you're trying to back up. Does this make sense? I'm not at all familiar with plesk, so I'm afraid I cant help discovering the file structure of that particular platform.

Comment: yes, this helps. thankyou! I just managed to do this, someone here showed me exactly what you are saying. I thought it was more complicated than what it was.. :)

Comment: It's worth noting that you can get unlimited private Git repositories over at Bitbucket.org. It doesn't have the social features of Github but if you're looking for simple code hosting then it's a good option.